# can verilog do `if defined(SOMETHING) ... `elsif defined(SOMETHING_ELSE) ... `endif?

Tags: verilog

I'm pretty sure I've done something like this in C before where I have a variety of choices but only one will be true at compile, and I'd like to do it for Verilog sims as well. I haven't found anything about it though. Here's what I'd like to do:

define on command line one of the FLASH_IS_??? names for the current run

in testbench file do:

```
`if defined(FLASH_IS_1MB)
    `define FLASH_TEA              19000000000 //19s max for 1MB erase cycle
`elsif defined(FLASH_IS_512KB)
    `define FLASH_TEA              12000000000 //12s max for 512KB erase cycle
`elsif defined(FLASH_IS_256KB)
    `define FLASH_TEA               6000000000 //6s max for 256KB erase cycle
`elsif defined(FLASH_IS_128KB)
    `define FLASH_TEA               4000000000 //4s max for 128KB erase cycle
`endif

...

#`FLASH_TEA; //wait for erase time

...
```

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
`ifdef FLASH_IS_1MB 
    `define FLASH_TEA              19000000000 //19s max for 1MB erase cycle
`elsif FLASH_IS_512KB
    `define FLASH_TEA              12000000000 //12s max for 512KB erase cycle
`elsif FLASH_IS_256KB
    `define FLASH_TEA               6000000000 //6s max for 256KB erase cycle
`elsif FLASH_IS_128KB
    `define FLASH_TEA               4000000000 //4s max for 128KB erase cycle
`endif
```

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks! Our existing code is of the `ifdef SOMETHING ... `else `ifdef SOMETHING ELSE `endif `endif variety. Not cool... :)